# sbt with java-home uses default jdk to compile java sources

Tags: java, sbt

I have a mixed scala/java project and have a host that has multiple jdks on it. The default java (via alternatives) is jdk8. If I build a project specifying a different java-home, java sources are still built using the default jdk on the path.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
```

`/usr/bin/java` is linked to `/etc/alternatives/java` which is linked to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8/bin/java` as per the host's setup.

```
$ sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk7 compile
....
[warn] Error reading API from class file : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: my/org/package/SomeJavaClass : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
....
$ javap -verbose target/scala_2.10/classes/my/org/package/SomeJavaClass.class | grep major
major version: 52
$ javap -verbose target/scala_2.10/classes/my/org/package/SomeScalaClass.class | grep major
major version: 51
```

As you can see, the java sources were compiled to java 8 (assuming a `java` process is spawned from the default path), while scala sources used the jdk7 to build. I am able to get the java sources to compile for java 7 by specifying javacOptions in the build definition:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source","1.7","-target", "1.7")
```

but I'd like to avoid having to do this in the build source and prefer to build for java 7 at compile time with sbt parameters if possible.

How could I get SBT to use a different java (assuming fork a java process and specify a full path)? Would this be considered an SBT bug if sbt doesn't spawn the javac from the java-home directory?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the target JVM for the Scala compiler in build.sbt or Build.scala:

scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andrew - `but I'd like to avoid having to do this in the build source and prefer to build for java 7 at compile time with sbt parameters if possible.`

Comment: in that case on the command line when running sbt you can do the following: JAVA_HOME=<path-to-jdk-home> sbt . This sets the java home path for this instance of sbt running only

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk7; sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk7 compile` - when doing that, classes from scala source show major version 50 and classes from java source 52.

Comment: Adding scalacOptions and javacOptions to build.sbt got both sources to major version 51.

Comment: this may seem like a silly question but does sbt -target:jvm-1.7 compile work at command line? i've never tried it, but i wonder if it will